# How to Start up external url chrome app with fullscreen

Tags: google-chrome-app, hosted-app

I'm publishing the chrome app. 
I need to open up "http://kangwodnd.cafe24.com/" with fullscreen mode.

in my manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "배드민턴 코트 예약시스템",
    "description": "Badminton Court Reservation System",
    "version": "0.44",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }
    },
       "permissions": [
        "fullscreen",
        "alwaysOnTopWindows"
    ]
}
```

and

I don't know what I have to do in background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create("http://kangwodnd.cafe24.com/",{

  });
});
```

It looks like publishing normally, but when I run the app. It's not working no alert no warning.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't open an external URL as a hosted app window.

To achieve what you want, you need to create your own local HTML file, and embed a [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) into it to show your webapp.